# How to check if a json path/value entries exists in a huge json object in oracle sql?

Tags: oracle

Let's say the json object is like :

```
{
    "title":"<title goes here>",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "name":"<name goes here>",
    "features": {
        "feature-id1":{
             "id":"090ccd9c-8930-4aa9-9aa3-f9c8e6747a27",
              "name":"feature1",
              "version":"1.0.0"
        }
        "feature-id2":{
             "id":"932twe8e-2184-4er9-5qw3-g4e9w9821w71",
              "name":"feature2",
              "version":"1.0.0"
        }
      ...
     }     
}
```

I want to check whether there exists a json path/value entries (or) a nested json object in the above json data.
I have tried with 
 `json_exists(json_column,'$.features?(@."feature-id1" == "{"id": "090ccd9c-8930-4aa9-9aa3-f9c8e6747a27","name":"feature1","version":"1.0.0"}")');`
But this is giving me an error "**JZN-00229: Missing parenthesis in paranthetical expression**".
Can't we use json_exists() to check for json objects/arrays with values?
In Postgresql this can be achieved by using the '@>' operator : 
`json_data->'features'->'feature-id1' @> 'provide the json value'`
Is there a way to achieve the same in Oracle SQL? I'm using Oracle 19c with latest patch(19.15).

Answer (score 0):

At least in Oracle (I don't know other database products - you mention Postgre and say it has capabilities that Oracle doesn't have), comparison filters like you are trying to apply only work for scalar values, not for nested objects.

If I understand what you are trying to do, then in Oracle you would do that with something like

```
json_exists(json_column,'$."features"."feature-id1"?(
     @."id"      == "090ccd9c-8930-4aa9-9aa3-f9c8e6747a27"
  && @."name"    == "feature1"
  && @."version" == "1.0.0"
  )'
)
```

although this is not exactly equivalent to what you were trying to do. Namely, this filter only ensures the existence of a key "feature-id1" with value a nested object that has **at least** the three keys "id", "name" and "version", with the prescribed values - but it ***may*** also have other keys. So the object value of "feature-id1" may not be **equal** to the prescribed object in your attempt, which has **exactly** three keys, no more. Will that work for you? Only you know.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy, This works as of now. What if I want to check nested objects/arrays in the source json object?? That will become more complex I guess. I just want to check a json object or the json key-value entries exist in a json object. Is there any other function that I can use other than json_exists() in the where clause of select stmt to filter the result.